# Calculating an interval from a timestamp in SAS

Tags: time, sas

I have some data:

```
data beforehave;
   input ID TIME_EVENT $ Activity $;
   datalines;
12345 07:03:875 Activity1
12345 07:04:004 Activity1
12345 07:05:062 Activity1 
12345 07:07:357 Activity2 
12345 07:10:743 Activity2 
23145 07:12:737 Activity1 
23145 07:14:065 Activity2 
23145 07:15:037 Activity2 
;
RUN;
```

I want to get to some data that looks like this where I am counting the time between steps but then resetting the counter to 0 every time the first Activity 1 appears;

```
data beforehave;
   input ID TIME_EVENT $ Activity $ TIME_TAKEN;
   datalines;
12345 07:03:875 Activity1 00:00:000
12345 07:04:004 Activity1 00:00:029
12345 07:05:062 Activity1 00:01:058
12345 07:07:357 Activity2 00:01:295
12345 07:10:743 Activity2 00:03:386
23145 07:12:737 Activity1 00:00:000
23145 07:14:065 Activity2 00:01:672
23145 07:15:037 Activity2 00:00:972
;
RUN;
```

I think I need to take the time the particular Activity occurred from the time the first `Activity1` occurred for that `ID`. I have thought of doing this in terms of an intermediate step whereby I create a field that updates to pull across the `TIME_EVENT` of the fist `Activity1`. This intermediate step would look like this;

```
data beforehave;
   input ID TIME_EVENT $ Activity $ TIME_INTER;
   datalines;
12345 07:03:875 Activity1 07:03:875
12345 07:04:004 Activity1 07:03:875
12345 07:05:062 Activity1 07:03:875
12345 07:07:357 Activity2 07:03:875
12345 07:10:743 Activity2 07:03:875
23145 07:12:737 Activity1 07:12:737
23145 07:14:065 Activity2 07:12:737
23145 07:15:037 Activity2 07:12:737
;
RUN;
```

To create this I could use the SAS first. function and have written this;

```
data OUT.DATA;    
   set IN.DATA;
   if first.Activity = 'Activity1' then TIME_INTER = TIME_EVENT;
run;
```

from this I just get a blank field.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Do you have any input data? or only datalines?

Comment: What is the meaning of the time values?  `07:03:875` does not look like a valid way to represent time.  It is not H:M:S since how could you have 875 seconds?  Perhaps the first two parts are minutes and seconds and the last part is milliseconds?  If so then why is it prefixed with `:` instead of `.` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my TIME_EVENT field was actually a character format, so that had to be recast as a time data-type. Also I only had a time stamp for the beginning of the last type of Activity so the TIME_INTERVAL became the time before the next Activity1 which was effectively meaningless. I therefore had to set this to 0. This code is basically the same as the one posted above by andrey_sz only with a couple of tweeks for those things mentioned above;

```
data OUT.DATA(drop=TIME_EVENT_prev);
    set beforehave;
    by ID;
    TIME_EVENT=input(TIME_EVENT,TIME8.);
    retain TIME_EVENT_prev;
    if first.ID then TIME_INTER = 0;
    else TIME_INTER = TIME_EVENT +(-TIME_EVENT_prev);
    TIME_EVENT_prev = TIME_EVENT;
    if last.logflag then TIME_INTER = 0;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data OUT.DATA(drop=TIME_EVENT_prev);
   set beforehave;
   by ID;
   retain TIME_EVENT_prev;
   if first.ID then TIME_INTER = 0;
   else TIME_INTER = TIME_EVENT +(-TIME_EVENT_prev);
   TIME_EVENT_prev = TIME_EVENT;
run;
```

Retain variable `TIME_EVENT_prev` is fixed on each row and before fixing on current row it has value from previous rows.

Comment: Thanks @andrey_sz. I have run this and all I get is 0s for each first.ID. Is the _prev a SAS function? How do I set what TIME_EVENT_prev is equal to? :-)

Comment: No, _prev is not a function. Try to remove 'drop=TIME_EVENT_prev' and see the values of it for each row. Also, what is format for TIME_EVENT? Text?

Comment: I think the issue I am having here is that TIME_EVENT is in fact text. Is there still a way to do this? Would I have to change the data-type first?

Comment: Yes, TIME_EVENT +(-TIME_EVENT_prev) will work for date-time format and difference will in secs.